# Place axis label at end of axis in Plot3D with axis origin

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, legending

I would like my axis labels to appear at the ends of my axes (much as would happen in a 2D plot) while using `Plot3D` and placing my `AxesOrigin` at `{0,0,0}`. Is there a simple way to achieve this?

```
p[i_] := ParametricPlot3D[{x, i, 5 (x^4 - 2 x^2) + 5}, {x, -2, 2}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, 
  Ticks -> None, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style["\[Phi]", FontSize -> 12], 
    Style["i", FontSize -> 12], Style["\[Tau]", FontSize -> 12]}]
dot[i_] := Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.02], Point[{0, i, 0}]}]
Show[{p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], dot[0], dot[1], dot[2], dot[3]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 4}, {-1, 7}}]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: see [mathematica-is-it-possible-to-put-axeslabel-for-3d-graphics-at-the-end-of-the-a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182676/mathematica-is-it-possible-to-put-axeslabel-for-3d-graphics-at-the-end-of-the-a)

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to create labels manually and place them. Not very appealing, but it gets the job done, I would be surprised if there isn't a better way to do this though.

```
p[i_] := ParametricPlot3D[{x, i, 5 (x^4 - 2 x^2) + 5}, {x, -2, 2}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1/2}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> True, 
  Ticks -> None, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, PlotStyle -> Red]
dot[i_] := Graphics3D[{PointSize[0.02], Point[{0, i, 0}]}]
l1 = Graphics3D[Text[Style["\[Phi]", FontSize -> 12], {-2.3, 0, 0}]];
l2 = Graphics3D[Text[Style["\[Tau]", FontSize -> 12], {0, 0, 9}]];
l3 = Graphics3D[Text[Style["i", FontSize -> 12], {0, 4.3, 0}]];
Show[{p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], dot[0], dot[1], dot[2], dot[3], l1, l2, 
  l3}, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1, 4}, {-1, 8}}]
```

[image]

Comment: You can use single Graphics3D